# How to pass a callback function to once().then() in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, callback, firebase-realtime-database

I have a separate model and a controller for a teachers list.

My `teacherModel.js` is:

```
app.factory('Teacher', [function() {
   function Teacher(teacher) {
     // constructor
   };
   Teacher.prototype = {
        setTeacher: function(teacher) {
            angular.extend(this, teacher);
        },
        getAllTeachers: function(callback) {
            var scope = this;
            var ref = firebase.database().ref('/xxx/teachers');
            ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
                teachersList = snapshot.val();
                scope.setTeacher(teachersList);
                // THERE'S A PROBLEM HERE...
                // I'm trying to pass this callback from the controller:
                callback;
            });
        }
    };  
    return Teacher;
}]);
```

Now from my controller I call the `getAllTeachers()` method with a callback function:

```
app.controller('teacherMainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Teacher', function($scope, Teacher){
    var teacher = new Teacher()
    teacher.getAllTeachers(function() {
       $scope.teachers = teacher;
       console.log($scope.teachers);
    });
}]);
```

Problem is `console.log($scope.teachers);` is not logging anything to the console. I don't think the callback is being executed at all.

Can someone help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better way to add functionality to the model data from controller after the data is asynchronously retrieved from firebase? Thanks.

Comment: You could simply `return ref.once('value);` in your getAllTeachers() since that returns a promise and do away with the callback so that in your controller, you can just call teacher.getAllTeachers().then(function (snapshot) { // assign snapshot}); to evaluate the result of the promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not calling the callback actually, use `callback()`

```
app.factory('Teacher', [function() {
   function Teacher(teacher) {
     // constructor
   };
   Teacher.prototype = {
        setTeacher: function(teacher) {
            angular.extend(this, teacher);
        },
        getAllTeachers: function(callback) {
            var scope = this;
            var ref = firebase.database().ref('/xxx/teachers');
            ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
                teachersList = snapshot.val();
                scope.setTeacher(teachersList);
                // THERE'S A PROBLEM HERE...
                // Try this
                callback();
            });
        }
    };  
    return Teacher;
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did indeed miss the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the fact that `once` returns a firebase promise so you can alter your code to the following:

```
app.factory('Teacher', [function() {
   function Teacher(teacher) {
     // constructor
   };
   Teacher.prototype = {
        setTeacher: function(teacher) {
            angular.extend(this, teacher);
        },
        getAllTeachers: function() {
            var scope = this;
            var ref = firebase.database().ref('/xxx/teachers');
            return ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {      
                return snapshot.val();
            });
        }
    };  
    return Teacher;
}]);
```

This would behave similarly to any `$http` request where it returns a promise. Now, in your controller, you can then call your `getAllTeachers()` like so:

```
app.controller('teacherMainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Teacher', function($scope, Teacher){
    var teacher = new Teacher()
    teacher.getAllTeachers().then(function (snapshotValues) {
        // What you returned in the promise above is populated in snapshotValues here
        $scope.teachers = snapshotValues;
    });
}]);
```

**Update**

If you want to use the [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service for your particular scenario, you can do the following:

```
app.factory('Teacher', ['$q', function($q) {
   function Teacher(teacher) {
     // constructor
   };
   Teacher.prototype = {
        setTeacher: function(teacher) {
            angular.extend(this, teacher);
        },
        getAllTeachers: function() {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            var scope = this;
            var ref = firebase.database().ref('/xxx/teachers');
            ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {      
                var val = snapshot.val();
                // Transform your data any way you want. 
                // Whatever you pass into resolve() will be available as a parameter in the subsequent then()

                defer.resolve(val);
            });

            return defer.promise;
        }
    };  
    return Teacher;
}]);
```

Using the method would still be the same. You simply just call `then()`

```
teacher.getAllTeachers()
    .then(function (whatYouPassedInResolve) {

});
```

Another thing to note is that in the `getAllTeachers` method inside of your factory, I did not handle any error cases. That would be achieved by rejecting the promise with `defer.reject(objectToSendBack)`. You pass in any data you want accessible when you deem that call a failure.

Just pass in a function for the second parameter to the `then(successCallback, errorCallback) to handle any rejected promises.

Comment: Thanks John. This works, however, I'm trying to avoid any dependency for controller on firebase. so if I my data store changes I can always change the model and accept a call back. For example, I really want to return an array or a processed object to controller rather than the default firebase 'snapshot' response.

Comment: I'd suggest then using the `$q` service to create a defer object and return it as a promise. Then, you can either resolve or reject the result of your firebase request (or a pre-processed like returning an array as you mentioned). Then, you normalize the behavior as you're returning an angular built-in promise object (same as `$http`). That way, callers of your service are evaluating $q promises and know nothing about the underlying service call.

Comment: Hi John, this seems better. I haven't used `$q` services before. I will check this out. Thanks. Perhaps you can edit the answer to include this instead? I think it'll help others more.

Comment: @Sadeep No worries. I updated the answer to include the use of `$q`.